# Normal permissions for running mysqld 

Tags: mysql, linux, file-permissions, chroot

I'm trying to run mysqld inside chroot environment. Herez the situation.

When I run mysqld as root, I can connect to my databases. But when I run mysql using init.d scripts(normal permissions), mysql gives me an error.

```
$ mysql --user=root --password=password
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

So I guess, I need to change file permissions of some files. But which ones? Oh and in case you are wondering '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' is owned by 'mysql' user.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html 
see the starting guide.

Comment: @vivek - None of those cases apply to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug with schroot. mysqld escapes chroot and interacts with systems's mysqld.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1625863 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/430224